# Sum Keys in Array And Map Against A 24 Hour Structure

Tags: php

I'm having the following problem and quite frankly no idea how to solve it:

Each array has a numeric value in key[0] and a time in key[1]. My goal is to map this output against a 24 hour period.

Sum all key[0] values where key[1] time is between 00:00 - 01:00, 01:00 - 02:00, etc.

If there are no values in a certain time period, "0" should be printed.

Here are the arrays that hold the values:

```
Array ( 

[4045862944400] => Array ( 
[0] => 192 
[1] => 23:52 
) 
[403274909688162] => Array ( 
[0] => 186 
[1] => 22:21 
) 
[402735273075459] => Array ( 
[0] => 311 
[1] => 04:29 
) 
[252948031457462] => Array ( 
[0] => 385 
[1] => 06:22 
) 
[400606749954978] => Array ( 
[0] => 287 
[1] => 05:01 
) 
[286755318061725] => Array ( 
[0] => 358 
[1] => 04:51 
) 
[399687880046865] => Array ( 
[0] => 257 
[1] => 21:51 
) 
[398332190182434] => Array ( 
[0] => 240 
[1] => 23:19 
) 
[397768486905471] => Array ( 
[0] => 311 
[1] => 05:38 
) 
[396907650324888] => Array ( 
[0] => 293 
[1] => 03:38 
) 
[394850557197264] => Array ( 
[0] => 496 
[1] => 05:12 
) 
[394121230603530] => Array ( 
[0] => 475 
[1] => 04:15 
) 
[69757766367627] => Array ( 
[0] => 488 
[1] => 04:01 
) 
[391602517522068] => Array ( 
[0] => 506 
[1] => 03:44 
) 
[390848830930770] => Array ( 
[0] => 437 
[1] => 06:05 
) 
[389975351018118] => Array ( 
[0] => 452 
[1] => 04:00 
) 
[242486689170043] => Array ( 
[0] => 525 
[1] => 04:13 
) 
[388151047867215] => Array ( 
[0] => 415 
[1] => 00:22 
) 
[387476447934675] => Array ( 
[0] => 502 
[1] => 04:51 
) 
[386620518020268] => Array ( 
[0] => 467 
[1] => 06:05 
) 
[215937481836499] => Array ( 
[0] => 359 
[1] => 01:10 
) )
```

The output should be an array that represents 24 hours and has the according sum of values for each hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea to get you going:

```
$hours = array();
foreach($input as $v) {
   $lowerHour = array_shift(explode(':', $v[1]));

   if(!array_key_exists($lowerHour, $hours)) $hours[$lowerHour] = 0;
   $hours[$lowerHour] += $v[0];
}

print_r($hours);
```

Comment: Hi @Andreas, that's a nifty approach. Thanks for that. It ouputs exactly what I need except a "0" for the hours where there is now value. Would you know how would you incorporate that?

Comment: G.W, not quite sure what you mean... could you elaborate please? :)

Comment: Sure @Andreas, my goal is to get an array, just like $hours but not only show the hours that have values but also the hours that don't have. i.e.

00:00 - 01:00 => 456
01:00 - 02:00 => 654
02:00 - 03:00 => 0  //no values so print 0
03:00 - 04:00 => 456
and so on

The final array should have hourly break down of 24 hours. Each hour should hold the sum of keys and if there are no values for a given hour, "0" should be printed.

Comment: In that case, when you do a for loop to display the hours, do something like `for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) { if(empty($hours[$i])) echo "0"; else echo $hours[$i]; }`

Comment: Yes, @Andreas that's what I need (show 0 for hours that don't have a value). Sorry for my rather poor explaining - as you can probably tell I'm fairly new to the world of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for that @Andreas - really helpful! So this should work if i put the for loop when  displaying $hours right (outside the foreach loop)? Because at the moment I'm getting a hole punch of "0"

Answer (score 1):

First build up an array with indexes representing each hour of your 24hour range (simple "for" loop, with a mktime() function)

Then for each item in your data array, sort them into the 24hour range array by index that represents that time period as a sub array with an key of say "children", adding to that time periods total as you iterate.

For display, loop through your first 24 hour array, with a sub loop for each child element